# Why isn`t the image shown here?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I want to display an image on a JFrame trough a JLabel but the only thing that is being displayed is the JFrame. And please say it in noob :)
Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;

public class Swing extends JFrame{
    public JLabel label;
    public ImageIcon image;

    public Swing() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        image = new ImageIcon ("image.png");
        label = new JLabel (image);
        add(label);
    }
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("some text.");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(2300, 1717);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(300, 100);
        frame.setTitle("title");

        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());     
    }


 }
```

Comment: Your `Swing` constructor is never called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not displayed because you did not tell your program to display it.

In java, the function main contains what your computer will run and compile.

I would define the image the same way you did but into main and the important part is to tell your program to display it.

Try this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
frame.add(label);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation
     (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Probably insteed of this

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

You wanted this

```
   JFrame frame = new Swing();
```